# What do the stars/skull above ships indicate?

Tags: windward

All of the ships that I've seen so far in the game have either a skull or 1-5 stars above them. What do they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They represent that ship's kill rating. 1 star indicates the ship has killed 1 ship, 2 means 2 kills and so on...

At 6+ kills, the indicator changes to the skull icon and that [ship/player is granted some additional critical strike chance](http://steamcommunity.com/app/326410/discussions/0/620713633840750319/#c620713633841679278). Player's kill ratings are lost upon death and upon changing regions. NPC ships may spawn with a non-zero kill rating and are more likely to do so the higher the level of the region/instance they spawn in.